# React native checkbox collapses accordion when it's own state changes

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I click on the checkbox to change state, the accordion that it's nested within also collapses.

It's very wierd; I can click the text bellow, and the accordion does not collapse.

This is the code for the component; look within CollapseBody:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import {Collapse,CollapseHeader, CollapseBody, AccordionList} from 'accordion-collapse-react-native'
import { loadLeagues } from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Checkbox from 'react-native-modest-checkbox'

class LeagueSelect extends Component {

            state = {
                modalVisible: false,
                checked: true
            }



    setModalVisible(visible) {
        this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadLeagues()
    }

    render() {
      return ( 
        <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        {console.log('in league', this.props)}
              <Modal
                animationType="slide"
                transparent={false}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                  Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                }}>

                <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>

                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>

                    <Collapse >
                        <CollapseHeader>
                            <Text>Leagues</Text>
                        </CollapseHeader>
                        <CollapseBody>
                            {this.props.league === null ?'' : this.props.league.map(
                                (v, i) => {
                                    return(
                                            <View>
                                                <Checkbox
                                                    label={v.acronym}
                                                    onChange={() => { this.setState({ checked: false})}}
                                                    checked={this.state.checked}
                                                />
                                                <Text>{v.acronym}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                    )
                                }
                            )}
                        </CollapseBody>
                    </Collapse>

                </View>

              </Modal>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(true);
                }}>
                <Text>Show Modal</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
      );
    }
  }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
      league: state.league.league
     }
   }

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loadLeagues })(LeagueSelect);
```

This is a video of the behavior; it's difficult to describe without actually being able to see it: https://streamable.com/sbqab

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't anything else going on that is interfering with it? I built a small sample project using the code you provided and it appears to be working fine.

[image: Working Demo]

One other thing (non-related) - you're using the same `checked` state for both boxes, so clicking one will change the status of the other.  I don't think this is what you want, so I went ahead and set up your state to keep an entry for each checkbox.

Here's a copy of the complete code running in that gif:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Modal, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Collapse, CollapseHeader, CollapseBody, AccordionList } from 'accordion-collapse-react-native'
import Checkbox from 'react-native-modest-checkbox'

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    checked: {},
  }

  // hardcoded props
  league = [
    { acronym: 'NBA' },
    { acronym: 'NFL' },
  ];

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const checked = this.league.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
      ...acc,
      [cur.acronym]: false,
    }), {});
    this.setState({ checked });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
          }}
        >
          <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
            <TouchableHighlight
              onPress={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
              }}
            >
              <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Collapse>
              <CollapseHeader>
                <Text>Leagues</Text>
              </CollapseHeader>
              <CollapseBody>
                {this.league === null ? '' : this.league.map(
                  (v, i) => (
                    <View key={v.acronym}>
                      <Checkbox
                        label={v.acronym}
                        onChange={() => this.setState({
                          checked: {
                            ...this.state.checked,
                            [v.acronym]: !this.state.checked[v.acronym]
                          }
                        })}
                        checked={this.state.checked[v.acronym]}
                      />
                      <Text>{v.acronym}</Text>
                    </View>
                  )
                )}
              </CollapseBody>
            </Collapse>
          </View>
        </Modal>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={() => {
            this.setModalVisible(true);
          }}>
          <Text>Show Modal</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The key pieces to note are the checkbox:

```
<Checkbox
  label={v.acronym}
  onChange={() => this.setState({
    checked: {
      ...this.state.checked,
      [v.acronym]: !this.state.checked[v.acronym]
    }
  })}
  checked={this.state.checked[v.acronym]}
/>
```

and the state initialization from the "props" (I've hardcoded these for my example):

```
// hardcoded props
league = [
  { acronym: 'NBA' },
  { acronym: 'NFL' },
];

...

componentDidMount() {
  const checked = this.league.reduce((acc, cur) => ({
    ...acc,
    [cur.acronym]: false,
  }), {});
  this.setState({ checked });
}
```

Comment: It's soooo weird; I literally copy and pasted the code that you created, and I'm getting the same result

Comment: Android or iOS? What version of RN? And you ran this code without anything else in your project and it still doesn't work?